gRPC server side template giving 'unexpected EOF'
I am trying to eliminate the need of proto files for running the gRPC/rpc services by directly parsing the interface that user will provide.
This interface will contain the list of methods that will be exposed over the RPC connection.
For example:
package main

import "gofr.dev/pkg/gofr"

// ExampleService Define the service interface with GoFr context
type ExampleService interface {
GetExampleData(ctx \*gofr.Context, request ExampleRequest) (ExampleResponse, error)
}

// ExampleRequest Define the request struct
type ExampleRequest struct {
ID   int    `json:"id"`
Name string `json:"name"`
}

// ExampleResponse Define the response struct
type ExampleResponse struct {
Status  string `json:"status"`
Message string `json:"message"`
}

Now the plan is to parse this interface to extract out the necessary fields, methods and structs.
I have made a parser that extracts out the information from interface and then populate it in this struct:
type ParsedInterface struct {
    InterfaceName string
    Methods       []ParsedMethod
}

type ParsedMethod struct {
    Name        string
    InputParams []ParsedParam
    ReturnTypes []ParsedType
}

type ParsedParam struct {
    Name string
    Type string
}

type ParsedType struct {
    Name   string
    Fields []ParsedField
}

type ParsedField struct {
    Name string
    Type string
}

This is working correctly till here, but for my third step :
i.e. to generate the go code for the gRPC client and server side i am using this generator.go
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "go/format"
    "text/template"
)

// GenerateCode generates the client and server code
func GenerateCode(parsedInterface *ParsedInterface) (string, string, error) {
    clientTemplate := `
package main

import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "google.golang.org/grpc"
)

type {{.InterfaceName}}Client struct {
    cc *grpc.ClientConn
}

func New{{.InterfaceName}}Client(cc *grpc.ClientConn) *{{.InterfaceName}}Client {
    return &{{.InterfaceName}}Client{cc: cc}
}

{{range .Methods}}
func (c *{{$.InterfaceName}}Client) {{.Name}}(ctx context.Context, req interface{}) (interface{}, error) {
    out := new(interface{})
    err := c.cc.Invoke(ctx, "/{{$.InterfaceName}}/{{.Name}}", req, out)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    return out, nil
}
{{end}}
`

    serverTemplate := `
package main

import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
    "google.golang.org/grpc"
)

type {{.InterfaceName}}Server struct {
    impl interface{}
}

func New{{.InterfaceName}}Server(impl interface{}) *{{.InterfaceName}}Server {
    return &{{.InterfaceName}}Server{impl: impl}
}

{{range .Methods}}
func (s *{{$.InterfaceName}}Server) {{.Name}}(ctx context.Context, req struct {
    {{range .InputParams}}{{.Name}} {{.Type}}
    {{end}}
}) ({{range .ReturnTypes}}{{.Name}} {{.Type}}{{end}}, error) {
    method := reflect.ValueOf(s.impl).MethodByName("{{.Name}}")
    if !method.IsValid() {
        return {{range .ReturnTypes}}{{.Name}}, fmt.Errorf("method {{.Name}} not found")
    }
    in := []reflect.Value{reflect.ValueOf(ctx)}
    {{range .InputParams}}in = append(in, reflect.ValueOf(req.{{.Name}})){{end}}
    out := method.Call(in)
    if len(out) != {{len .ReturnTypes}}+1 {
        return {{range .ReturnTypes}}{{.Name}}, fmt.Errorf("unexpected number of return values")
    }
    if err, ok := out[{{len .ReturnTypes}}].Interface().(error); ok && err != nil {
        return {{range .ReturnTypes}}{{.Name}}, err
    }
    resp := struct {
        {{range .ReturnTypes}}
            {{.Name}} {{.Type}}
        {{end}}
    }{}
    {{range $i, $type := .ReturnTypes}}
        {{if $type.Fields}}
            resp.{{.Name}} = {{.Type}}{
                {{range $field := $type.Fields}}
                    {{$field.Name}}: out[{{$i}}].Elem().FieldByName("{{$field.Name}}").Interface().({{$field.Type}}),
                {{end}}
            }
        {{else}}
            resp.{{.Name}} = out[{{$i}}].Interface().({{$type.Type}})
        {{end}}
    {{end}}
    return resp, nil
}
{{end}}

func (s *{{.InterfaceName}}Server) Register(grpcServer *grpc.Server) {
    {{.InterfaceName}}_RegisterService(grpcServer, s.impl)
}
`

    clientTmpl, err := template.New("client").Parse(clientTemplate)
    if err != nil {
        return "", "", err
    }

    serverTmpl, err := template.New("server").Parse(serverTemplate)
    if err != nil {
        return , "", err
    }

    var clientBuffer, serverBuffer bytes.Buffer

    err = clientTmpl.Execute(&clientBuffer, parsedInterface)
    if err != nil {
        return "", "", err
    }

    err = serverTmpl.Execute(&serverBuffer, parsedInterface)
    if err != nil {
        return "", "", err
    }

    clientCode, err := format.Source(clientBuffer.Bytes())
    if err != nil {
        return "", "", err
    }

    serverCode, err := format.Source(serverBuffer.Bytes())
    if err != nil {
        return "", "", err
    }

    return string(clientCode), string(serverCode), nil
}

For the client side i am able to generate the code successfully,
but the server-side template is giving me this error:
template: server:60: unexpected EOF
I want to generate both the client and server-side code using these templates but i doubt maybe there is some error inside them.
So for example, the client-side code generated by this method is:
package main

import (
        "context"
        "fmt"
        "google.golang.org/grpc"
)

type ExampleServiceClient struct {
        cc *grpc.ClientConn
}

func NewExampleServiceClient(cc *grpc.ClientConn) *ExampleServiceClient {
        return &ExampleServiceClient{cc: cc}
}

func (c *ExampleServiceClient) GetExampleData(ctx context.Context, req interface{}) (interface{}, error) {
        out := new(interface{})
        err := c.cc.Invoke(ctx, "/ExampleService/GetExampleData", req, out)
        if err != nil {
                return nil, err
        }
        return out, nil
}

But for server side code getting error:

template: server:60: unexpected EOF


Erm, I'm sorry, but I have to ask: why are you trying to use gRPC without proto files? One of the benefits of proto's is that you can generate the request/response types not just for golang, but for pretty much any other major language in use today. Once compiled, your application doesn't use the proto files themselves, it's all baked in anyway (as in buf or protoc generates go code for you already). I'm really struggling to grasp why you've decided to go down this path...

@EliasVanOotegem my aim is to simplify the use of gRPC protocol in golang. One who don't know much about proto buffers etc and only want to use a simple gRPC api should be able to do it.
Also it is a kind of development experiement  i want to carry out.
Can you please help me in identifying the issues

What I'd do is just supply people who don't know anything about protobuf the client buf/protoc generates, and let them use that. You can just provide them with a go package that contains the types and a basic client after all. That's making things easier. What you're doing is over-complicating things in every possible way imaginable. Say your proto defines a FooService, generate the .pg.go files, and you'll find that in there, there will be a function like NewFooServiceClient. It's as easy as that.

That client implements the correct interface (as per proto definition), that package contains all the request/response types, so there's no ambiguity as to what calls take/return what types. It's as clear as it gets. If you're looking to cater to people who would even struggle to make sense of something that cut & dry, then the only correct course of action is to tell them to read just the "getting started" part of the docs for an example on how to call grpc.Dial, because with the pb.go files, that's all they need to do

@elias-van-ootegem is correct and @umang-mundhra (you) should consider that you'll probably provide something that's not only as complex but probably more complex and also different which means you'll end up supporting it too. That said, your server template is badly-formed, you have several range actions that don't have associated end's (lines 25,31,34)
